# Rails route constraint on subdomain not matching regex route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have a route that looks like this:

```
match '/', to: 'browse#city_companies', constraints: { subdomain: /[a-z\-]+-[a-z]{2}/ }, :via => [:get]
```

The regex `/[a-z\-]+-[a-z]{2}/` used in the constraint will match for example: "birmingham-al", but not "south-carolina". Which would be the behavior I'm trying to achieve.

However, rails is using this route on both "birmingham-al" and "south-carolina" which is not what I want. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Add a end of string character to the regexp - `..[a-z]{2}$/` or `..[a-z]{2}\z/`

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot. That fixed it. Thanks. If you post that as the answer I can close the question. Or maybe I should just delete, your call @yoavmatchulsky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use the end of string character:

```
/[a-z\-]+-[a-z]{2}\z/
```

or

```
/[a-z\-]+-[a-z]{2}$/
```

and the route can be:

```
get '/', to: 'browse#city_companies', constraints: { subdomain: /[a-z\-]+-[a-z]{2}\z/ }
```